# When / How to Create / Destroy Room Database

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I was wondering if someone could either point me to documentation to / clarify when to create or destroy a room database instance. Also how you would effectively open / close it ?

If I have a `RoomDatabase` object that gets injected via dagger to a presenter is that cool and then I just access various Daos? I'm worried about having the object lingering and taking up memory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Injecting the `RoomDatabase` into your presenter you could Inject a `DataManager` Singleton class.

This `DataManager` can hold your `WeakReferences` to your `DAO`s . Based on when you try to access the data, first check if you have it in memory pass it on to the presenter, if not you can then Lazily access the `RoomDB` to load data into memory and then pass on to the presenter.

In this way, there is a Single Source of Truth that accesses/manages your data.