# When should I build the room database instance?

Tags: android, android-room

First time posting a question and I'm a coding noob so sorry if I do something wrong.

I check around and found one answer which is somewhat similar to my question: **[When / How to Create / Destroy Room Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031574/when-how-to-create-destroy-room-database)**

However I am not using dagger, nor do I know how to use it.

I wanted to ask when should you build your room database instance? Suppose my app uses the database throughout, should I build it in the OnCreate of the Main Activity? Or should I only build it once the users tries to access some functionality that requires it?

**This is the code in question:**

```
instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), MovieDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
```

So basically when is the best time to run the above code?

Please let me know if this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: `Or should I only build it once the users tries to access some functionality that requires it?` probably this. it prevents the resources being allocated to it _until_ it is actually needed. but it depends on your scenario :) also, welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Don't forget to use Double-Checked Locking with Singleton.

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. No idea how to mark it as correct

Comment: well i was simply responding with a comment, so you can't mark this as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **build** itself does not open/connect the database and is therefore not resource intensive so this can be done anywhere. Probably, in general, the best place is to build in the MainActivity.

It is not until you actually try to do something with the database (insert/update/delete/query) that the open/connection is then done, which can be relatively resource intensive. Hence, why by default, Room does not allow you to do anything on the main thread (using `.allowMainThreadQueries` when building, can be used to override this restriction).

You can force an open/connection e.g. by getting a **SupportSQLiteDatabase** using. for example, `theBuiltDatabase.openHelper.writableDatabase` (theBuiltDatabase representing the database that has been ***partially*** built) (this can run on the main thread irresepective of `allowMainThreadQueries`). However, you probably don't want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your Database `Instance` will be built as `Singleton` and you can access it anywhere as it will be created only once.

Please follow this [codelab tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) to get a clear vision of using Room

Answer (score 1):

Create an Application Class where you will create a singleton object of it.You can go through this [example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/). It explains all your requirements.